# Invisible htaccess redirection to dedicated server IP adress

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

Here is my .htacess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^code/$ http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/code.php [L]
```

but when I go the http://domain.com/code/ the url is rewrited to xxx.xxx.xx.xx/code.php

Is it possible to make an invisible redirection to a Dedicated Server IP adress ?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a reverse proxy, what it does is that the first web server receives the requests and connects to the second server on  xxx.xxx.xx.xx ip address. In this way the user never has direct access to the  xxx.xxx.xx.xx server.